# Exclude duplicate classes from 2 local .aar files in libs folder

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar

Can we remove duplicate classes from the local .aar files in libs folder.

```
Duplicate class com.regina.first.core.C$RefreshWebClientQueryIds found in modules jetified-regina-runtime.jar (abc.aar) and jetified-gms-sdk-debug-runtime.jar (xyz.aar)
```

I have tried using-

```
implementation (files('libs/abc.aar')) {
   exclude 'com.regina.first.core.C'
}
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['xyz.aar'])
```

But got the following response from the gradle although i am already using gradle version 4.0.1 -

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
Possible causes:
The project 'atv-retail-app' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 4.0.1 and sync project

The project 'atv-retail-app' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html) in order to exclude a package/group from the dependency you should use the syntax below

```
 dependencies {
            implementation('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4') {
                exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah right but that is true for the gradle dependency not for local .aar files.

Comment: Maybe a combination of the above and this [configuration](https://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/gradle/gradle-exclude-transitive-dependency-example)